# sorting based on a dynamic variable in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort my dataframe in python pandas but the issue I am facing is that the dataframe is to be sorted on multiple columns, which is a user input.

Basically I have stored the columns on which it is to be sorted as an array -

```
keys=np.array(['kzip9','kzip8','kzip7','kzip6','kzip5'])
```

Then I am trying to sort as -

```
temp_0=df.sort([keys])
```

This gives me the following error -

> ValueError: Cannot sort by duplicate column ['kzip9' 'kzip8' 'kzip7' 'kzip6' 'kzip5']

But when I put a column name instead of 'keys' in the sort statement, it works fine.

Comment: Do you need `temp_0=df[np.sort(keys)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) for sorting `array` and then select by subset:

```
temp_0=df[np.sort(keys)]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. But this is still not working fine. I do not get any errors as such now but now i get only the columns in 'keys' array. The other columns are not displayed and the ones displayed are not sorted a well

Comment: So need sort columns? then use only `df.columns = df.columns.sort_values()`

Comment: sort_values() should do the trick - you can also pass ascending boolean array if you need a mix of asc and desc

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, you can't use a `ndarray` as your keys.  Use `tolist`.

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 10))).add_prefix('kzip')

keys = np.array(['kzip9', 'kzip8', 'kzip7', 'kzip6', 'kzip5'])

df.sort_values(keys.tolist())

   kzip0  kzip1  kzip2  kzip3  kzip4  kzip5  kzip6  kzip7  kzip8  kzip9
1      0      2      0      4      9      7      3      2      4      3
4      2      8      7      5      8      4      7      6      1      5
3      8      7      6      4      7      6      2      6      6      5
0      0      2      7      3      8      7      0      6      8      6
2      3      6      7      7      4      5      3      7      5      9
```